# Laravel 5.1 Pagination URL Error 404 Not Found

Tags: php, model-view-controller, pagination, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am using Laravel 5.1 on WAMP Server 2.5.

And I have this error while working on pagination.

> 404 Not Found

While I run my site locally using this **php artisan serve**

> php artisan serve --port=212

I run to my site index url **http://localhost:212/displays**.
The pagination works fine, its pagination link work fine on every page **http://localhost:212/displays?page=2**.

But when I run it manualy without **php artisan serve** (**http://localhost/bookstore/public/displays**), the pagination link goes wrong. The pagination link originally printout **http://localhost/bookstore/public/displays/?page=2**, but it automatically change into **http://localhost/displays?page=2** when the page fully rendered.

Is anyone have same problem like me? Glad if any of you could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because you're meant to set the web root on your server to the `public` folder (and Laravel assumes that that's the case).

As it is, your web root is set to somewhere two levels above the `public` folder, so when Laravel tries to redirect to `/displays?page=2` it tries to send you to the wrong folder.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. Laravel and artisan have it's ways to do this.